# Counting number of words, characters and lines

Tags: c

I want to count the number of characters, words and newlines in a program. My code look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int nw, nl, nc, c;
    nw = nc = nl = 0;
    for (c = getchar(); c != EOF; c = getchar()) {
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c != '\n' || c != '\t' || c != ' ') {
            for (c = getchar(); c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' '; c = getchar()) {
                ++nc;
            }
            ++nw;
            ++nc;
            if (c == '\n')
                ++nl;
        } else
            ++nc;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d", nc, nw, nl);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
smith  book
c c++ 
bug
```

Output: `9 0 13`

What's wrong with this program?
I am a beginner. Forgive if I made any mistake.

Comment: please enable compiler warnings *and read them*.  The expression `c==('\n'||'\t'||' ');` does not do what you think it does.  In no language would that check if `c` was euqal to any of those.  For that you want `c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' '`  make sure to think about why that is, if you want to learn C

Comment: can you give more details about wrong answer ?
Have you tried to debug it with gdb or other debugger tool?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the test `c != '\n' || c != '\t' || c != ' '` is always true. You mean to test if `c` is either `' '`, `'\t'` or `'\n'`, ie: a word separator, but the expression should be `c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' '` or more generally `isspace(c)`.
- you count the number of newline characters `'\n'` but you should add 1 if the last line does not end with a newline.
- similarly, you count a word for each sequence of white space, but you should ignore leading white space.

A simpler way to handle these corner cases is to keep the last character and test for transitions:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int nw, nl, nc, c, lastc;
    nw = nc = nl = 0;
    for (lastc = '\n'; (c = getchar()) != EOF; lastc = c) {
        nc++;
        if (c == '\n')
            nl++;
        if (isspace(lastc) && !isspace(c))
            nw++;
    }
    if (lastc != '\n')
        nl++;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nc, nw, nl);
    return 0;
}
```

Since boolean expressions evaluate to `0` or `1`, this code can be simplified as:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int nw, nl, nc, c, lastc;
    nw = nc = nl = 0;
    for (lastc = '\n'; (c = getchar()) != EOF; lastc = c) {
        nc++;
        nl += (c == '\n');
        nw += (isspace(lastc) && !isspace(c));
    }
    nl += (lastc != '\n');
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nc, nw, nl);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @erik258 mentioned, enable compiler warnings & read them all.
You should add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compiling flags.

`c==('\n'||'\t'||' ');` (you seem to have edited this from your original post) is in essence doing a boolean comparison. i.e. `c` is `true` if `\n`, `\t` or   is `true`, which all three of those technically are in this case.
What you end up with here can be represented as `c==(true||true||true)` or `c==true` or more accurately `c==1` no matter what the value of `c` actually is, which isn't what you seem to be after.
Just thought that you might appreciate that clarification.

Another thing you might like to know... The declaration of your loop:
`for(c=getchar();c!=EOF;c=getchar())`
Can be declared more simply as `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)`